# How to check for multiple attributes in XPath?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'd like to select stylesheets in an XHTML document, which contain not only description, but also href.

For example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="123"/>
```

should be selected, and

```
<link rel="stylesheet"/>
```

should not.

At present, I'm doing it like this:

```
foreach (XmlNode n in xml.SelectNodes(@"//link[@rel='stylesheet']"))
{
    if (n.Attributes["href"]==null||n.Attributes[""].Value==null)
    {
        continue;
    }
    var l = Web.RelativeUrlToAbsoluteUrl(stuffLocation, n.Attributes["href"].Value);
}
```

but I suspect there's a much better way of doing this. Is there?

Comment: Second part of the test should read `n.Attributes["href"].Value==null` :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `and @href` to the attribute expression:

```
//link[@rel='stylesheet' and @href]
```

This should allow you to omit the check altogether:

```
foreach (XmlNode n in xml.SelectNodes(@"//link[@rel='stylesheet' and @href]"))
{
    var l = Web.RelativeUrlToAbsoluteUrl(stuffLocation, n.Attributes["href"].Value);
}
```